# Сhecking data updates on the site using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension, one of the functions of which will be to check for the appearance of new data on the site after clicking the start button in a pop-up window.
Our site has a table in which new data appears from time to time, we need to receive in chrome.storage only those data that appeared on the site after pressing the start button, and stop receiving after pressing the stop button.
Maybe someone knows some APIs for writing such functionality, or maybe some functions for it, I would be grateful for any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but configure it carefully to watch only required nodes

Comment: Didn't know about that before, it might look good, thanks